# Transformations.map and MediatorLiveData crashing app with null object reference

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-architecture-components

Not sure what's going on.  I'm running two queries that I'm then merging and transforming using a MediatorLiveData and Transformations.map.  I'm using this almost exact same code for two other queries without issue. But when I use it for these particular queries the app crashes on start with the errors below.

***Please note: I've tried observing the MediatorLiveData and I can get the results of both queries without error.  Only when I try to run them through the Transformations.map do I get errors and app crash.***

**Here's the observe I used to test the MediatorLiveData that works fine:**

```
    viewModel.getAllValidEventsLiveDataMerger().observe(this, new Observer<AllValidEventsSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable AllValidEventsSnapshot allValidEventsSnapshot) {
                if (allValidEventsSnapshot.isComplete()) {
                    List<Event> nonRepeatEventList;
                    List<Event> repeatEventList;
                    List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
                    nonRepeatEventList = allValidEventsSnapshot.getValidNonRepeatableEventsSnapshot().toObjects(Event.class);
                    repeatEventList = allValidEventsSnapshot.getValidRepeatableEventsSnapshot().toObjects(Event.class);
                    eventList.addAll(nonRepeatEventList);
                    eventList.addAll(repeatEventList);
                    Log.d(TAG, "EVENTLIST: " + eventList.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

**Here's the observe that goes through the Transformations.map:**

```
    viewModel.getAllValidEventsLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<Event>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Event> eventList) {
                if (eventList != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "EventList: " + eventList.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

Here's the code:

**ViewModel.java**

```
private static final String TAG = "ViewModel";

private FirebaseRepository repository = new FirebaseRepository(getApplication());

public ViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
}

    /*
     *
     * Selected Device Events Live Data
     *
     */

    private FirebaseQueryLiveData selectedDeviceEventsLiveData = new FirebaseQueryLiveData(repository.getSelectedDeviceEventsQuery());

    @NonNull
    public FirebaseQueryLiveData getSelectedDeviceEventsLiveData() {
        return selectedDeviceEventsLiveData;
    }

    /*
     *
     * Selected device nonRepeat valid events Live Data
     *
     */

    private FirebaseQueryLiveData validNonRepeatEventsLiveData = new FirebaseQueryLiveData(repository.getValidNonRepeatEventsQuery());

    @NonNull
    public FirebaseQueryLiveData getValidNonRepeatEventsLiveData() {
        return validNonRepeatEventsLiveData;
    }

    /*
     *
     * MediatorLiveData that merges all valid events (repeatable and nonRepeatable)
     *
     */

    //MediatorLiveData method that merges all valid repeatable and nonRepeatable liveData
    //into a eventList of Event Objects
    private MediatorLiveData<AllValidEventsSnapshot> allValidEventsLiveDataMerger() {
        final MediatorLiveData<AllValidEventsSnapshot> mediatorLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        final AllValidEventsSnapshot current = new AllValidEventsSnapshot();
        mediatorLiveData.addSource(validRepeatEventsLiveData, new Observer<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
                current.setValidRepeatableEventsSnapshot(querySnapshot);
                mediatorLiveData.setValue(current);
            }
        });
        mediatorLiveData.addSource(validNonRepeatEventsLiveData, new Observer<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
                current.setValidNonRepeatableEventsSnapshot(querySnapshot);
                mediatorLiveData.setValue(current);
            }
        });
        return mediatorLiveData;
    }

    //Accessor method to get the result of the mediatorMerge
    public MediatorLiveData<AllValidEventsSnapshot> getAllValidEventsLiveDataMerger() {
        return allValidEventsLiveDataMerger();
    }

    /*
     *
     * Transforming the MediatorLiveData that merges repeatable and nonRepeatable valid events
     * into one combined eventList
     *
     */

    //live data that transforms our MediatorLiveData repeatable and nonRepeatable eventList
    private final LiveData<List<Event>> allValidEventsLiveData =
            Transformations.map(allValidEventsLiveDataMerger(), new GetAllValidEvents());

    //sub-class that implements Function to convert our two valid eventLists into one
    private class GetAllValidEvents implements Function<AllValidEventsSnapshot, List<Event>> {

        @Override
        public List<Event> apply(AllValidEventsSnapshot input) {
            List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (input != null && input.isComplete()) {
                List<Event> repeatEventList = input.getValidRepeatableEventsSnapshot().toObjects(Event.class);
                List<Event> nonRepeatEventList = input.getValidNonRepeatableEventsSnapshot().toObjects(Event.class);

                //merge valid repeat and nonRepeatable event lists
                eventList.addAll(repeatEventList);
                eventList.addAll(nonRepeatEventList);
            }
            return eventList;
        }
    }

    //accessor method to get our transformed users/devices/admin live data into the NavDrawer object
    public LiveData<List<Event>> getAllValidEventsLiveData() {
        return allValidEventsLiveData;
    }
```

**Queries:**

```
        //getValidNonRepeatEvents query using FirebaseQueryLiveData class
    public Query getValidNonRepeatEventsQuery () {
        query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("devices")
                .document(docID)
                .collection("events")
                .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("eventDate", firstDayThisWeekObj);

        return query;
    }

    //getValidRepeatEvents query using FirebaseQueryLiveData class
    public Query getValidRepeatEventsQuery () {
        query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("devices")
                .document(docID)
                .collection("events")
                .whereEqualTo("repeats", true);

        return query;
    }
```

**AllValidEventsSnapshot.java object class**

```
   public class AllValidEventsSnapshot {

    private QuerySnapshot validRepeatableEventsSnapshot;
    private QuerySnapshot validNonRepeatableEventsSnapshot;

    //default constructor
    public AllValidEventsSnapshot() {
    }

    public QuerySnapshot getValidRepeatableEventsSnapshot() {
        return validRepeatableEventsSnapshot;
    }

    public void setValidRepeatableEventsSnapshot(QuerySnapshot validRepeatableEventsSnapshot) {
        this.validRepeatableEventsSnapshot = validRepeatableEventsSnapshot;
    }

    public QuerySnapshot getValidNonRepeatableEventsSnapshot() {
        return validNonRepeatableEventsSnapshot;
    }

    public void setValidNonRepeatableEventsSnapshot(QuerySnapshot validNonRepeatableEventsSnapshot) {
        this.validNonRepeatableEventsSnapshot = validNonRepeatableEventsSnapshot;
    }

    public boolean isComplete() {
        return (validRepeatableEventsSnapshot != null && validNonRepeatableEventsSnapshot != null);
    }
}
```

**FirebaseQueryLiveData.java**

```
    public class FirebaseQueryLiveData extends LiveData<QuerySnapshot> {
    public static final String TAG = "FbaseQueryLiveData";

    private Query query;
    private final MyValueEventListener listener = new MyValueEventListener();
    private ListenerRegistration listenerRegistration;

    private boolean listenerRemovePending = false;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    public FirebaseQueryLiveData(Query query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    private final Runnable removeListener = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listenerRegistration.remove();
            listenerRemovePending = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        super.onActive();

        Log.d(TAG, "onActive");
        if (listenerRemovePending) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(removeListener);
        }
        else {
            listenerRegistration = query.addSnapshotListener(listener);
        }
        listenerRemovePending = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        super.onInactive();

        Log.d(TAG, "onInactive: ");
        // Listener removal is schedule on a two second delay
        handler.postDelayed(removeListener, 2000);
        listenerRemovePending = true;
    }

    private class MyValueEventListener implements EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null){
                Log.e(TAG, "Can't listen to query snapshots: " + querySnapshot + ":::" + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
            setValue(querySnapshot);
        }
    }
}
```

**Below is the traceStack error that I'm getting:**

```
    2018-12-16 14:29:15.238 27558-27558/com.vuedeu.vuedeu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vuedeu.vuedeu, PID: 27558
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vuedeu.vuedeu/activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class viewModels.ViewModel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class viewModels.ViewModel
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:207)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102)
        at activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:193)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:199)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102) 
        at activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:193) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap.get(SafeIterableMap.java:47)
        at android.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap.putIfAbsent(SafeIterableMap.java:65)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData.addSource(MediatorLiveData.java:87)
        at viewModels.ViewModel.allValidEventsLiveDataMerger(ViewModel.java:102)
        at viewModels.ViewModel.<init>(ViewModel.java:126)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:199) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102) 
        at activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:193) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Your crash isn't from the code in the question. You are crashing in your `ViewModel` constructor, on a call to `allValidBlackoutsLiveDataMerger()`, and neither the constructor nor that method are in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the response CommonsWare.  Please note: that I'm obfuscating my code.  allValidBlackoutsLiveDataMerger() is allValidEventsLiveDataMerger().  I just forgot to change it in the error stack trace (fixed it in the stack trace for consistency)

Comment: Also, added the constructor to the ViewModel.java class.

Comment: `currentNode.mKey` is null inside `SafeIterableMap`, and the key is the LiveData? This shouldn't happen, but consider keeping the mediator by `allValidEventsLiveDataMerger()` as a field, instead of creating a new mediator each time.

Comment: Thanks for the response EpicPandaforce.  I'm not sure why SafeIterableMap is null.  As I mentioned above I've tested the MediatorLiveData and confirmed that data is being received without error/null.  Additionally, I'm doing other Transformations.map functions the exact same way and do not get null errors.  The only difference is that the problem code is using queries that are querying data from the same collection of documents, while others are transforming queries from different collections.  I'm wondering if this is a bug with Firestore.

Answer (score 13):

Solved!  So it appears the null pointer exception was being caused because my queryLiveData methods were placed after the Transformations.map method.  In the example above, I had put the queryLiveData methods above the Transformations.map for clarity (removing unrelated methods in the process), not realizing that I had put the methods in a different order.

So, to sum up: the code above works without problems.  I just had to put the queryLiveData methods above the Transforms.map method (which is actually shown above).  The strange thing about the order is that the mediatorLiveData didn't seem to care about the order but the Transformations.map did.